# breaking a loop when enter is pressed

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to break the loop once Enter is pressed, while writing data to a file. This is what I have so far. I also don't want to limit the number of time the loop is run either... (example output is below)

```
def main():
    myfile = open('friends.txt','w')
    friend = input('Enter first name of friend or Enter to quit')
    age = input('Enter age (integer) of this friend')

while friend != '':

    for n in range():
        friend = input('Enter first name of friend or Enter to quit')
        age = input('Enter age (integer) of this friend')

        myfile.write(friend +'\n')
        myfile.write(str(age) +'\n')

    myfile.close()
main()
```

This is how to output is supposed to be when its ran right.

```
Enter first name of friend or Enter to quit Sally
Enter age (integer) of this friend 20
Enter first name of friend or Enter to quit Sam
Enter age (integer) of this friend 24
Enter first name of friend or Enter to quit 
File was created
```

Comment: `for n in range()` --> `TypeError: range expected 1 arguments, got 0`

Comment: Is that the indentation in your code or did you transcribe it badly? badly indented Python code is nonsense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a couple of errors in your code, such as using `range()` and indentation and using `input` for a string, when `raw_input` may have been a better choice.

To do what you want, you should put the `write` at the beginning of your loop, and after asking for the name, check if it's empty and, if it is, `break`. Code is below:

```
def main():
    myfile = open('friends.txt','w')
    friend = raw_input('Enter first name of friend or Enter to quit')
    age = int(raw_input('Enter age (integer) of this friend'))

    while friend != '':

        while True:
            myfile.write(friend +'\n')
            myfile.write(str(age) +'\n')
            friend = raw_input('Enter first name of friend or Enter to quit')
            if not friend:
                break
            age = int(raw_input('Enter age (integer) of this friend'))

        print('File was created')
        myfile.close()
main()
```

Comment: If using python 3, the `input` function would be appropriate.

Comment: OP seemed like a beginner and I wanted to put something that worked in either version, hence 'may have been a better choice'.

Comment: @Brian for sure a beginner, thank your for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
def main():
    myfile = open('friends.txt','w')

    while True:
        friend = input('Enter first name of friend or Enter to quit: ')
        if not friend:
            myfile.close()
            break
        else:
            age = input('Enter age (integer) of this friend: ')
            myfile.write(friend +'\n')
            myfile.write(str(age) +'\n')



main()
```

**Output:**

```
Enter first name of friend or Enter to quit: Mack
Enter age (integer) of this friend: 11
Enter first name of friend or Enter to quit: Steve
Enter age (integer) of this friend: 11
Enter first name of friend or Enter to quit: 

Process finished with exit code 0
```